# GatsbyImage loads low resolution image on mobile

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-plugin

I am trying to figure out how to make `GatsbyImage` to display high res image while on mobile. For example HQ with **16:9** ratio image is uploaded through CMS (`Primsic` in this context), than my front loads it via graphql into Gatsby and being displayed as full window size picture with `objectFit` set to `COVER`. Perfectly works for desktops, however as soon as I change view to mobile, becuase it takes 100% height of viewport and gatsby-image-plugin looks like taking only viewport width - rendered image is pixelated due to being lower res than needed.. I tried to use all possible APIs in the plugin to force higher res. Forcing breakpoint defaults did not help either.

Any idea what could be done? Maybe only possible solution will be to upload 2 variants of the image cropped to desired viewport ratio straight into Prismic and load appropriate image that way? I am sure there have to be nice automated method for this situation..

Answer (score 0):

> I am sure there have to be nice automated method for this situation..

Indeed there is: it's called [`withArtDirection`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#withartdirection).

By default, the Gatsby displays different image resolutions at different screen sizes, but it also supports art direction, which basically displays different images on different screen sizes

To do this, you can use the `withArtDirection` function. You need all (or the number of breakpoints you want to apply) images available from GraphQL, and you should be able to write a media query for each size.

The first argument is the default image. This is displayed when no media queries match, but it is also used to set the layout, size, placeholder and most other options. You then pass an array of "art directed images" which are objects with media and image values.

```
import { GatsbyImage, getImage, withArtDirection } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
export function MyImage({ data }) {
  const images = withArtDirection(getImage(data.largeImage), [
    {
      media: "(max-width: 1024px)",
      image: getImage(data.smallImage),
    },
  ])
  return <GatsbyImage image={images} />

}
```

If the screen is less than `1024px` wide, it will display `smallImage`. Otherwise, it will display `largeImage`.

A full example can be found at: https://paulie.dev/posts/2021/04/gatsby-plugin-image-with-art-direction/